# $\min \int_{0}^{\infty} (a f'(x)^2+b f(x)^2+c |f(x)|) dx$

Tags: mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

Can Mathematica solve

$\min_{f(x) s.t. f(0)=f_0} \int_{0}^{\infty} (a f'(x)^2+b f(x)^2+c |f(x)|$)dx  ?

I tried

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
DSolve[EulerEquations[a f'[x]^2 + b f[x]^2 + c Abs[f[x]],f[x],x],f[x],x]
```

but I don't know what to do with the result

```
Solve[(\int_{1}^{f[x]}\frac{1}{Sqrt{C{1]+2(\frac{cAbs[K[1]]}{2a}+\frac{bK[1]^2}{2a})}}dK[1])^2==(x+C[2])^2,f[x])
```

PS: Sorry for the bad math formatting, I can't use math blocks. This is an old problem: ["Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" with math blocks](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code-with)

Comment: Please post the output of your code by direct copy-paste, don't try to LaTeXify it.

Comment: @corey979  The output is a visual formula. Should I take a screenshot?

Comment: closed form solution?

Comment: @Xminer Yes, if possible

Comment: do you have any additional condition for variable,$a$,$b$,$c$ and function $f(x)$ itself?

Answer (score 3):

## `DSolve` solution for positive/negative halfplane

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
eulereqs = EulerEquations[a f'[x]^2 + b f[x]^2 + c Abs[f[x]], f[x], x]

(* Out[] *)
2 b f[x] + c Abs'[f[x]] - 2 a f''[x] == 0
```

`DSolve` can't solve this right away because of the `Abs'[x]` term, but if we assume `f[x] > 0` (or `f[x] < 0` to the same effect) we can get solution families for the positive and negative half-plane.

```
eqpos = FullSimplify[eulereqs, f[x] > 0]
eqneg = FullSimplify[eulereqs, f[x] < 0]
DSolve[eqpos, f[x], x]
DSolve[eqneg, f[x], x]

(* Out[]*)
c + 2 b f[x] == 2 a f''[x]
c + 2 a f''[x] == 2 b f[x]
{{f[x] -> -(c/(2 b)) + E^((Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a]) C[1] + E^(-((Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a])) C[2]}}
{{f[x] ->   c/(2 b)  + E^((Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a]) C[1] + E^(-((Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a])) C[2]}}
```

## Phase space plot

If we don't want to confine our solution to the positive/negative special case but still get a good idea how our solutions look like, we can instead visualize the solutions with a phase space plot, where we plot the trajectories `{f[x], f'[x]}`. To do that we first do a simplification, where we replace `Abs'[x]` by `Sign[x]`

```
eq = eulereqs /. Derivative[1][Abs] -> Sign

(* Out[] *)
2 b f[x] + c Sign[f[x]] - 2 a f''[x] == 0
```

Through the introduction of helper variable `g[x]==f'[x]` we can see, that our  second order system in `f` is equivalent to a system of two first order ODEs:

```
{f'[x]==g[x],
 g'[x]==(b/a)f[x] + (c/(2 a)) Sign[f[x]]}
```

Now to get the correct slope or vector direction of the trajectory in a vector plot we want the rise `dg` and the run `df` which we can get as

$$\frac{\text{d}g}{\text{d}f}=\frac{\frac{\text{d}g}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}}=\frac{\frac{b}{a}f+\frac{c}{2a}\text{sign}(f)}{g}$$

and feed that to a `VectorPlot` or `StreamPlot`. Let's also use `Manipulate` to make it interactive and easy to explore the effect of different `{a, b, c}` parameter values.

```
Manipulate[
  StreamPlot[
    {g, b/a f + c/(2 a) Sign[f]}
    , {f, -3, 3}, {g, -3, 3}
    , FrameLabel -> {"f(x)", "f'(x)"}
  ]
  , {{a, 1}, 0, 5}
  , {{b, 2}, -5, 5}
  , {{c, 3}, -5, 5}
]
```

[image: Interactive phase space plot]

To generate a trajectory as function for further computations we can use `NDSolveValue` like this:

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3},
    sol = NDSolveValue[{f''[x] == b/a f[x] + (c/(2a)) Sign[f[x]],
                        f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f, {x, -10, 10}];
    GraphicsColumn[{
        Plot[sol[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All],
        ParametricPlot[{sol[x], sol'[x]}, {x, -3, 3}]
    }]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just for completeness, do you also know how to solve the concrete optimization problem with fixed initial position and optimizable initial derivative? (I'm mostly interested in the min, not the argmin) For $a=c=1,b=0$, I got $4/3 p_0^{3/2}$ through manual computations; do you get the same?